# html textarea, text is hidden until a it moves to a new line

Tags: html, sharepoint, internet-explorer-9, textarea

First post and question here so I hope I don't break too many rules or ask a stupid question.

I've got a problem with a textarea tag with Internet Explorer 9. The code is:

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextAreaId" cols="20" rows="5"> Text here </textarea>
```

Css: color: #2a2a2a; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;

The problem is, when you open the page and look at the box where the text is supposed to be, it is not. In fact, the font seems to have changed to white (the background color is white) and the scroll bars are gone. You can click into the box and mark it and copy paste the text out, so the text is there. The funny thing is that when you resize/change the css that effect the box, everything appears. Even if you simply move the IE9 window the scrollbar and text reappears.

I don't know what to look for, what to search on in google or here or if it is a bug in IE9, since I've not had this problem on other browsers. I've tried to search and spent almost an hour on it and I'ld like some directions. Any ideas? Do you need to know more about the code?

Comment: did you add the `color:black;` property to the `textarea`'s css?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant CSS lines?

(textarea, #myTextAreaId)

Comment: The code you posted above in isolation will work just fine, so something else must be happening.  You possibly have some CSS rule which is changing the text colour.  Hit F12 and look at the element inspector to see why it is taking these styles.

Comment: Looking in the dev console for that box, I have the following css:

color: #2a2a2a;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;

I'm pretty sure I've got no scripts or css that touch that box. But I'll recheck that meanwhile. I'm not sure what to call it but, when I make the browser change the css so that the box change accordingly, the text reappears. This means that if I use the dev console to change the font color, it remains hidden. But if I change the font or font size, or resize the box, the text and scroll bar appears.